# Determine the largest prime factor using a while loop and a for loop

Tags: java

I wanted to use a for and a while loop to obtain the prime factors of a number. My while loop example works fine which I have posted below my for loop example. However, my for loop does not work, and i am guessing that I can't use a continue in the same manner that I used it in the while loop. If this is true, then how would I accomplish this. I have not been able to find a basic beginners example of this using a for loop. Thanks

// My getting largest prime factor using a for loop

```
public class  LargestPrime{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int number = 36;
        int largestPrime = 0;

        for ( int i = 2; i <= number; i++){
            if (number % i == 0){
                largestPrime = i;
                number /= i;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(" largest prime = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

//*******************************************************************
//*******************************************************************

```
 public class LargestPrime {

    //    gettting largest prime using a while loop
    public static int getLargestPrime(int number) {

        if (number <= 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        int largestPrime = 0;
        int count = 2;
        while (count <= number) {
            if (number % count == 0) {
                largestPrime = count;
                number = number / count;
                continue;
            }
           count++;
        }

        return largestPrime;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `continue` in a `for` loop executes the *update* part (`i++`), which your `while` loop didn't.

The other problem is that you're printing inside the loop.

There are multiple way to fix this:

1. Do `i--` before `continue`, so it evens out to nothing with the `i++`. This is a fairly common way to handle this.

   Since you don't have any code after the `if` statement, you don't need the `continue`.

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
       if (number % i == 0) {
           largestPrime = i;
           number /= i;
           i--; // to retry same `i` value
       }
   }
   ```
2. Do the `i++` "yourself", i.e. not as part of `for` loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; ) {
       if (number % i == 0) {
           largestPrime = i;
           number /= i;
           continue;
       }
       i++;
   }
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; ) {
       if (number % i == 0) {
           largestPrime = i;
           number /= i;
       } else {
           i++;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use a `while` loop inside the `for` loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
       while (number % i == 0) {
           largestPrime = i;
           number /= i;
       }
   }
   ```

   That can be shortened to:

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++)
       for (; number % i == 0; number /= i)
           largestPrime = i;
   ```

   Though rather than assign `largestPrime` repeatedly, you could do this:

   ```
   for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
       if (number % i == 0) {
           largestPrime = i;
           do {
               number /= i;
           } while (number % i == 0);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Andreas. I really appreciate you showing me multiple ways in which to work this problem. Now knowing how to solve the problem  with a for loop, while loop, and a do while loop helps me to understand the logic behind the code.

Comment: Does someone get to the point where they know when to use a specific type of loop statement versus another through formal instruction, trial and error or just personal preference?